# Фразеологизм "выступать с блеском"

Tags: фразеология

Какие синонимы и антонимы есть у фразеологизма "выступать с блеском"?

Answer (score 1):

Антонимичный фразеологизм: потерпеть фиаско

Answer (score 1):

**Синоним:** **вызвать, произвести  фурор**  — шумный публичный успех, сопровождающийся проявлением восторга ◆ Он произвел тогда в Праге настоящий фурор своим необычным, ярким выступлением.

Фурор (от лат. furor — неистовство), шумный успех, всеобщее восторженное одобрение.

**Антоним**: **провалиться с треском.** Мне удалось подслушать их разговор, из которого я понял, что с треском провалился. [Карен Шахназаров. Курьер (1986)]

Answer (score 0):

С блеском — превосходно, блестяще, то есть *выступать с блеском* значит *выступать успешно, отлично, великолепно, превосходно*. Антонимичными будут сочетания: *выступать провально, неуспешно, плохо, ужасно, неудачно*.

Answer (score 0):

**Синонимы:**
 ***выступать*** блестяще, с шиком, ярко, с успехом, уверенно, удачно, ответственно, прекрасно, удивительно, роскошно, великолепно, ослепительно, восхитительно, превосходно, блистающе, блистательно;
**выступление, исключительное по своим положительным качествам; блистательный успех; блистательное выступление.**

*Я чувствую в себе **хорошо подготовившегося, интересного человека,** у которого есть твердое намерение выступить **блестяще**...*
   ***Прекрасное, яркое выступление*** певцов вызвало горячий отклик у слушателей... Наш старший концертный хор **блестяще** открыл сезон в Малом зале ...
*Готовьтесь и репетируйте, чтобы выступить **блестяще.** Не теряйте **уверенности в себе**, и тогда вы произведете впечатление **знающего** человека...*

**Антонимы:**
 ***выступать*** тускло, неприметно, убого, невыразительно, блёкло;
потерпеть крах, неудачу, провал, катастрофу, облом...